# In SAS, how to plot counts over weeks including zero counts?

Tags: plot, count, sas, zero, week-number

I am trying to create a plot in SAS that shows the number of lab results individual laboratories submit each week over the course of the year. I have managed to plot this out, but the plot skips weeks in which the laboratory submitted zero lab results, i.e. the count would be zero.

```
data testlabs;
input labdate:datetime22.3 labname$;
cards;
08JAN2019:09:40:37.000 A
07AUG2019:09:36:16.000 A
08AUG2019:13:16:51.000 B
21APR2019:09:33:54.000 B
22APR2016:12:47:51.000 B
08JUN2019:09:25:50.000 B
09JAN2019:13:48:24.000 A
10JAN2019:12:21:02.000 C
19FEB2019:14:40:39.000 C
09MAR2019:09:38:48.000 C
20NOV2019:09:50:30.000 A
07AUG2019:14:03:55.000 A
09MAR2019:09:31:39.000 B
09JUN2019:12:11:29.000 B
04APR2019:17:00:00.000 B
26NOV2019:13:05:28.000 C
09JUN2019:09:38:50.000 C
06MAY2019:12:44:20.000 C
08MAY2019:10:14:52.000 A
08JUN2019:08:43:17.000 A
02DEC2019:12:26:51.000 A
05MAY2019:12:53:17.000 B
06SEP2019:09:52:36.000 C
10MAR2019:09:31:41.000 A
08MAR2019:09:40:40.000 C
14JUL2019:09:38:59.000 B
08JAN2019:10:40:37.000 A
;
run;

proc sql;
create table testlabs1 as
    select distinct count(*) as lab_count,
    labname,
    put(datepart(labdate),weeku6.)as wk
    from testlabs
    where year(datepart(labdate))>2018
    group by wk, labname
    order by labname, wk
    ;quit;


symbol color=blue interpol=join;
    proc gplot data=testlabs1;
        plot lab_count*(wk);
        by labname;
        run;quit;
```

This creates three plots with points only on weeks with at least one lab. I would like to plot all 52 weeks of the year, including weeks where the count is zero.

Comment: If the data isn't there it can't be plotted, SAS doesn't know if it's missing or 0. If you have SAS ETS you can use that to add in the empty time periods and then plot them.

Answer (score 1):

You need a process that can create something from nothing.  The COMPLETETYPES option in SUMMARY/MEANS will do that.

```
data testlabs;
   input labdate:datetime22.3 labname$;
   lbdate = datepart(labdate);
   format lbdate weeku6.;
   cards;
08JAN2019:09:40:37.000 A
07AUG2019:09:36:16.000 A
08AUG2019:13:16:51.000 B
21APR2019:09:33:54.000 B
22APR2016:12:47:51.000 B
08JUN2019:09:25:50.000 B
09JAN2019:13:48:24.000 A
10JAN2019:12:21:02.000 C
19FEB2019:14:40:39.000 C
09MAR2019:09:38:48.000 C
20NOV2019:09:50:30.000 A
07AUG2019:14:03:55.000 A
09MAR2019:09:31:39.000 B
09JUN2019:12:11:29.000 B
04APR2019:17:00:00.000 B
26NOV2019:13:05:28.000 C
09JUN2019:09:38:50.000 C
06MAY2019:12:44:20.000 C
08MAY2019:10:14:52.000 A
08JUN2019:08:43:17.000 A
02DEC2019:12:26:51.000 A
05MAY2019:12:53:17.000 B
06SEP2019:09:52:36.000 C
10MAR2019:09:31:41.000 A
08MAR2019:09:40:40.000 C
14JUL2019:09:38:59.000 B
08JAN2019:10:40:37.000 A
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary data=testlabs completetypes nway;
   class labname lbdate / mlf;
   output out=testlabs2(drop=_type_ rename=(_freq_=lab_count));
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would only work each week has a record in the data set somewhere? If all groups were missing a group it would be missed, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to join your aggregate with a cross join of the `wk` x `labname` combinations.
The join will supplement the aggregate combination coverage, forcing a full coverage.

Example:

```
data weeks;
  do week = intnx ('week', '01jan2019'd, 0) by 7 while (year(week) <= 2019);
    output;
  end;
  format week weeku6.;
run;

data labs;
  do labname = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'; output; end;
run;


proc sql;
create table testlabs1 as

select 

    labs.labname,
    year(weeks.week) as year,
    weeks.week,
    coalesce(aggregate.lab_count,0) as lab_count

from 

    labs

cross join 

    weeks

left join 

(
    select distinct count(*) as lab_count,
    labname,
    intnx('year', datepart(labdate), 0) as yr format=year4.,
    intnx('week', datepart(labdate), 0) as wk format=weeku6.
    from testlabs
    where year(datepart(labdate))>2018
    group by yr, wk, labname
) aggregate

    on aggregate.labname = labs.labname
     & aggregate.wk      = weeks.week

order by
    year, labname, week    

  ;
quit;



symbol color=blue interpol=join;
    proc gplot data=testlabs1;
        plot lab_count*(week);
        by year labname;
        where year = 2019;
        run;quit;
```